# World Map without break line at 180 Meridian (Russia)

Tags: qgis, boundaries, antimeridian, russia, break

I want to create a map of the world (in my case Winkel Tripel but could be Miller or Equal Earth as well) showing Russia's full extent to the right, like in this example - which might be a very common task:

[image: How the extends should be]

Unfortunately I´m running out of ideas to solve this problem.

The project measurements are set up to WGS 84, based on the shape layers you get from Natural Earth Data - but it doesn´t even worked with any other shape layer from other sources.

I tried to reproject the Russian layer to "Asia Lambert Conic", fixed the geometry, dissolved it, exported it, imported it - even into a blank project. Nothing worked. The Russian layer is always showing up distorted.

[image: Reprojection settings I used in QGIS]

[image: The distorted result]

I came up with the idea that the bounding box, respectively the map extent, might not be correct. I´m not sure if this is the right track. But by testing this: I created a bounding box out the Russian layer extend and reprojected this with the result it became a this line stick to right:

[image: Original bounds and the reprojected result]

And if this theory is right I´m not quite sure how to solve it.

Comment: two options that come to my mind right now 1) split your polygone in 2 pieces along the meridian line, 2) use a procejction that is centered with russia in the middle (they exist for WK III etc, too)

Answer (score 6):

There are several options

### 1. World polygons provided by QGIS

You can set your project CRS to  Equal Earth (8857)

In the coordinate box at the bottom of the screen, type world:
[image]

This is what you will get:
[image]

### 2. Split your own geometries along the antimeridian of the chosen CRS

Another alternative as mentioned in a comment, if you really need to handle your own geometries around the antimeridian, is to split the ones that need to.

You can get the main process [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443895/splitting-polygons-crossing-the-antimeridian/443919#443919) without taking care of the PyQgis part.

In short, create a line from north to south pole at the antimeridian, buffer it by a tiny amount, split your geometry layers by this buffered line.

### 3. Use the  Globe Builder plugin

[image]

Comment: Hi Kasper, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately none of your answers worked for me. 

1.) Good to know, but it only provides a quick way to get a world shape layer and the problem isn´t solved by changing the CRS. For perfomance reasons I prefer to work in 3857 and set the final CRS in the layout/export settings

2.) Splitting the geometry also want provide the deserved  result.

3.) I know the globe builder. It´s nice for what it´s made but you also have a "split" part of russia stick to Alaska.